# There is any standard process to send confirmation email to the community user whenever their email address gets updated?

Tags: community, force.com

Would it be possible to send a confirmation email to the community user whenever their email address gets changed similar to how Salesforce does that for a standard user email address change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it looks like this is not possible natively. You can vote this idea.

[Verification E-Mail change for Community User](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DxnxAAC)

But using trigger you can manually send the email. Because in workflow you will not get old email address to send the email.